# Plotting a categorical terra raster with a colour map

Tags: raster, r, terra

I'm trying to plot a categorical `terra` raster object with an explicit colour for each level, like you'd do with a land cover raster, but running into problems when the raster doesn't have every level of the factor in it.

First create a raster with numeric values 1 to 10, make categorical, and plot:

```
r2 = rast(matrix(1:10,2,5))
r2 = as.factor(r2)
levels(r2) = data.frame(value=1:10, desc=paste0("L",1:10))
plot(r2)
```

[image]

Great, now I want to plot with every odd level coloured red and every even level coloured blue, so I make a palette of length 10:

```
rb = rep(c("red","blue"),5)
plot(r2, col=rb)
```

[image]

Great, but suppose my raster doesn't have every level? For example, let's make a copy of the raster and set the first cell into a level 2:

```
r2c = r2
r2c[1] = 2
plot(r2c, col=rb)
```

[image]

And now the colours have flipped and its not alternating with the 10 factor levels any more. Level 10 (blue) is not the same colour as level 8 (red).

I think what is happening is that the colour specifies colours for all values that *exist* in the raster, not all values that exist in the levels. So if I drop the first element of the palette (because there's no level 1 in the raster any more) I get this:

```
plot(r2c, col=rb[-1])
```

[image]

which is what I'm after. But this is a problem, because it means whenever I have a colour map that contains values that aren't in the raster (because maybe its a crop from a larger set), I have to subset the colour palette according to which values are still present in the cropped raster. I can't find a simple way to say "L10" is "blue", and "L3" is "yellow" and so on. Or have I missed it?

Edit: the solution might be in `coltab` but I think that requires making a full 255-row colour palette. Doable, but not neat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`coltab` is not as painful as it may seem (the docs are a bit behind the facts). You can do

```
r2 = rast(matrix(1:10,2,5))
r2 = as.factor(r2)
levels(r2) = data.frame(value=1:10, desc=paste0("L",1:10))
# first color-table value is zero, so starting with "blue"
coltab(r2) = rep(c("blue", "red"), 6)
plot(r2)
```

And the colors now stay the same

```
r2c = r2
r2c[1] = 2
plot(r2c)
```

Nevertheless, your point remains valid. It would be useful to have stable color/class combinations by linking the colors to the known levels, whether they are present or not. I have now implemented that in terra version 1.5-50.

With that version, you can also set a color table by ID

```
library(terra)
r <- rast(ncols=3, nrows=2, vals=c(10:12, 23:25))
coltab(r) <- data.frame(values=c(10:12, 23:25), cols=rainbow(6))
plot(r)
```

And that should become the canonical approach, I think, as it is the clearest and most flexible way to do it.

Comment: I think the problem with coltab is that it requires entries for rows 0 to max(r), which is awkward when my numeric values are 37 codes spread out in the range 0 to 255 (eg the 1-5 are various water classes, 100-105 are forest classes, 200-206 are agriculture, etc). Given a data frame with only 37 rows (of value, desc, colour) I need to splay that out into 255 rows to use in a coltab?

Comment: fair enough, see appended answer

Answer (score 5):

see a solution using ggplot and tidyterra. You may need to use `drop = FALSE` on the `scale_fill_*` call:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.21
library(tidyterra)
#> ── Attaching packages ────────────────────────────────── tidyterra 0.1.0.9002 ──
#> 
#> Suppress this startup message by setting Sys.setenv(tidyterra.quiet = TRUE)
#> ✔ tibble 3.1.7     ✔ dplyr  1.0.9
#> ✔ tidyr  1.2.0
r2 = rast(matrix(1:10,2,5))
r2 = as.factor(r2)
levels(r2) = data.frame(value=1:10, desc=paste0("L",1:10))


library(ggplot2)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'ggplot2'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:terra':
#> 
#>     arrow
rb = rep(c("red","blue"),5)


ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data=r2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rb)
```

[image]

```r
r2c = r2
r2c[1] = 2


ggplot() +
  geom_spatraster(data=r2c) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = rb, drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don't think proposing a completely different graphics system fixes a problem with the plot function.